# How to find the RAM type in command prompt in Android?

Tags: command-line, ram

I am trying to find out what the memory type of my Android phone is, i.e. if the device is LP4 or LP5 type.

On Windows PC, there is `wmic` command to get this system information. However, I can't find the equivalent for Android.

Is there any way from the command line that we can find out if the device is LP4 or LP5? Like accessing the shell and finding out the memory type.

Comment: `At Windows PC's wmic is there to get this system information` no [`wmic` stopped working for detecting DDR for more than a decade and you need other methods to do that](https://superuser.com/a/1540441/241386)

Comment: On my Pixel 4a the app [Device Info HW](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.deviceinfohw) shows LPDDR4x.